# AngularJS Modal Popup

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm really new to Angular.  I'm trying to recreate the modal sample at this link https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/  I am having no luck with it!  I created a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/018Ed7RG3Y0GoAlK7a14?p=catalogue I just need to be able to open a modal on a button click.  I'm getting the error message Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ModalDemoCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Here's my view

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleAnimation()">Toggle Animation ({{ animationsEnabled }})</button>
<div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
```

Here's my controller:

```
angular.module('crm.ma', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('crm.ma').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ModalDemoCtrl, function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

$scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

$scope.animationsEnabled = true;

$scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
                return $scope.items;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};

$scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
};
```

});

```
angular.module('crm.ma').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ModalInstanceCtrl, function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

$scope.items = items;
$scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
};

$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
});
```

Comment: your plunkr is broken.

Comment: @PankajParkar sorry about that.  I put the code in the index.html file.  You should be able to see it now.

Comment: you need to include `angular.js & ui-bootstrap.js` before your `script.js`

Comment: @PankajParkar this is a very small part of my application.  In the actual application they are both included.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a corrected fork of your plunk:  http://plnkr.co/edit/6djuhA8ohMkrWW7zohg1?p=preview.
You just had some minor syntax errors.

JAVASCRIPT

```
var app = angular.module('crm.ma', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

$scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

$scope.animationsEnabled = true;

$scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
                return $scope.items;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };

});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance)   dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="crm.ma">

<head>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.0.js"></script>
<script src="ModalDemoCtrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
  </script>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleAnimation()">Toggle Animation ({{ animationsEnabled }})</button>
  <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
  </div>
  </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: I changed my code to match yours.  I'm still getting no errors, but if I add my controller <script src="app/components/common/ModalDemoCtrl.js"></script> to the index.html page, it comes back with no errors and a blank page.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @hollyquinn, Did you get this working?  Sorry, I was out for a few days for medical.

Answer (score 5):

You need to fix this line:

```
angular.module('crm.ma').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ModalDemoCtrl, function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {    
//  what is this, huh? ------------------------------------^
```

Correct code:

```
angular.module('crm.ma').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {
```

You have similar problem with `ModalInstanceCtrl`.

You also missing `ng-app="crm.ma"` attribute.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/VDhDAHM2beVtYYsJBXoi?p=preview

Comment: I fixed the line of code, but it still doesn't work.  ng-app is included in my actual application.  This is a huge application, I'm just added the pages that I have a question about on Plunker.

Comment: ReferenceError: ModalInstanceCtrl is not defined(anonymous function) @ ModalDemoCtrl.js:36
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module crm.ma due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngAnimate due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngAnimate' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this the only script file I need to add to index.html for modal to work?  <script src="scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.1.4.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: `ModalInstanceCtrl` is similar to what I explained in the answer. You also need templates, or better 0.14.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js file. Just check the demo I posted with fixed code.

Comment: Ok, I went to your plunker and changed my code to match yours.  I've included the script files just like you have.  It still doesn't work.  I don't get an error message, I get a blank page.  The blank page goes away if I remove the  <script src="app/components/common/ModalDemoCtrl.js"></script> reference in my index page.

Comment: @hollyquinn, check out my plunk, based on your code.  I used your index.html, not your modal.html.